# Nextjs13 AppRouter, Add a custom class to the body tag for a specific page

Tags: next.js13, app-router

Using the AppRouter of Nextjs 13, how can I customize the body/html tags of my inner page?

I have a root layout:

```js
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  return (
    <html lang="en" className={`bg-primary`}>
      <body>
       {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and in `app/myPage/[id]/layout.tsx` I have a nested layout:

```js
export default function MyPageLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

I have not figured out how can I override/update the tags defined in the RootLayout for a specific url.

In this particular case I would like to add the css property `overflow: hidden` to the body tag for this url specifically `https:/0.0.0.0/myPage/XX`

Answer (score 1):

Got here, looking for same thing. Only way to achieve this, I created an empty `layout.tsx` file inside page structure, set as client component and modified using useEffect (to prevent document is undefined).

**File Structure:**

```
root foolder/
└── src/
    └── app/
        └── route-name/
            ├── page.tsx
            ├── layout.tsx
            └── error.tsx
```

**Layout Component (`layout.tsx`):**

```
'use client'

import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Layout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add('overflow-y-hidden');
    
    // unmount action
    return () => document.body.classList.remove('overflow-y-hidden');
  }, [])


  return children
}
```

This way you can still use `RootLayout` and modified it or include tags.